# Find how many different float values I have in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, floating-point, greatest-common-divisor

In order to solve a section from a problem, in which I'm given **n** pairs of integers **x** and **y**, I need to find how many different **x/y** are there. (the precise value, with decimals)

1.

Of course I could just iterate through all the previous pairs and see if the same **x/y** value occurred before, but that would take, I believe, **(n^2)/2** time.

I tried using a hash table, the it doesn't seem to function very well with float values. Maybe it would work with a very good hash function.

2.

Considering that **x** and **y** are integers, I tried a different approach to the problem:

- Compute the greatest common divisor for each pair
- Divide **x** and **y** with the GCD
- Use a matrix m[max_value_of_x][max_value_of_y] and do this:

  ```
  if ( m[x][y] ) { ; } else { m[x][y] = 1 ; cnt++ ; }
  ```
- After doing this for all the pairs, the **cnt** should be number of different float values.

Although this could run, I think, in a decent amount of time; it is definitively not space efficient. In the problem actually, the max value for **x** and **y** is 1000, but the memory allocated is quite low.

Comment: So the pairs `(6,2)` and `(9,3)` would be considered the same?

Comment: You could sort them after reducing them, it doesn't even have to be by value, it could be lexicographically - all you need is for identical fractions to end up next to each other. After that, just count the runs of identical fractions. Takes a lot less space.

Comment: Sounds like you could just loop through the pairs, placing `x/y` into a `std::set`, and then get the size of the set. I think that would be O(n log n).

Comment: Yes, the pairs (6,2) and (9,3) are the same, since 6/2 = 9/3 = 3.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MBo 's solution using a set :

```
struct cmp_div {
    bool operator ()(const std::pair<int, int>& xy1, const std::pair<int, int>& xy2) const {
        // x1/y1 < x2/y2
        return xy1.first*xy2.second < xy2.first*xy1.second;
    }
};

std::set<std::pair<int, int>, cmp_div> c;
c.emplace(6, 2);
c.emplace(9, 3);
std::cout << c.size(); // == 1
```

Comment: Very nice. Are you doing tech's homework for him, though? A slight improvement would be to reduce the fraction first or use long longs to perform the comparison to avoid int overflow.

Comment: Also, MBo should note that all the answers and commenters naturally avoid floating point comparisons, although I believe they would work fine in this case.

Comment: @Steger wouldn't they have some opportunity to stab you in the back (as floats like to do) and compare two very-near fractions as equal?

Comment: Note that solution with set using comparator will (most likely) have the same O(NlogN) time as sorting, but the code is shorter and elegant

Comment: Where can I find more information on how this comparator works when using sets?

Comment: @harold Two fractions x1/y1 and x2/y2 with x1,y1,x2,y2 between 1 and 1000 are either equal or have a relative difference of at least one in a million (proof left as exercise to reader). IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point is more than enough to identify such a fraction uniquely, **as long as the programmer does not do something stupid such as comparing up to epsilon with an arbitrary epsilon** (Here, for instance, no epsilon is necessary as there is only a single rounding in both `x1/y1` and `x2/y2`. They each may not be equal to the mathematical quantity, but assuming the fractions are…

Comment: mathematically equal, then `x1/y1` and `x2/y2` are each equal to the nearest floating-point number to the rational that is the common mathematical value of the two fractions)

Answer (score 0):

You can store x/y pairs in list or array, and sort this list with comparator function, which compares x1*y2 and x2*y1  - note that all calculations are in integers. After sorting (NlogN), walk the list and count different values (comparing neighbours only)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be storing all the x/y  values in a set and avoid duplicate entries.
This can be achieved by

```
      set < float > store ; // choose the datatype according to the precison needed .
      // If arr[] is the given array containing pair x and y .
      store . clear () ; .
      for ( i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++)
       {  x = arr[i].first ; y = arr[i].second ;
          float y = (x/gcd(x,y) / (y/gcd(x,y)) ; // For precison round the values   
           store.insert ( y ) ;
        }
```

Comment: I believe that all divisions in `(x/gcd(x,y) / (y/gcd(x,y))` are integer division, which is fine for `x/gcd(x,y)` and `y/gcd(x,y)` but means that the value of `y` is off by up to one. In addition dividing by the GCD is unnecessary. `float q = (float)x / y;` would be correct, I think.